# How to get unique random values in Dynamic Add / Remove input Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, random

I have created Dynamic Add/Remove fields. Everything is working perfectly. The only problem is that there is a hidden field having `name="auth_key[]"`.

For that, I want random values. So I use `value="<?php echo rand(); ?>"`. However, it creates the same random values for all the fields that are added. I want unique random values for all the fields that are added.

Following is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var wrapper = $("#member-fields");
  var add_button = $("#add-member-fields");

  var x = 1;
  var availableAttributes = <?php echo json_encode($get_user_emails); ?>;
  var previousValue = "";

  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x++;
    var element = $('<div id="user-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user_email[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_status[]" value="Unverified" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="auth_key[]" value="<?php echo rand(); ?>" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_member_field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

    element.fadeIn("slow").find("input[name^='user_email']").autocomplete({
      autoFocus: true,
      source: availableAttributes,
    });
    wrapper.append(element);
  });

  wrapper.on("keyup", "#user_email", function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in availableAttributes) {
      if (availableAttributes[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        isValid = true;
      }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
      this.value = previousValue
    } else {
      previousValue = this.value;
    }

  });

  wrapper.on("click", "#remove_member_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).closest('#user-fields').remove();
      x--;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Team Members</b></center>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Member's Registered Email</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Role in Project</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_email[]" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_status[]" value="Verified" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="auth_key[]" value="<?php echo rand(); ?>" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</button>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="member-fields">

    </div>

    <p class="help-block"><i>To add member please register new User, if already not registered.</i></p>

  </div>

</div>

<?php
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $args = array(
      'role'         => 'backer',
      'exclude'      => array( $user->ID ),
     );
    
    $users = get_users( $args );
    $get_user_emails = wp_list_pluck( $users, 'user_email' );
    
    ?>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `uniqid()` in php returns a unique id, [look at this] for js uuid. That looks more like something you want to identify than a random number. Also it's not that pretty to put php code inside js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in the JS part instead, inside the click event when you're adding the new field add the following code :

```
element.find('[name="auth_key[]"]').val( Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) );
```

```js
var wrapper = $("#member-fields");
var add_button = $("#add-member-fields");
var x = 1;
var availableAttributes = "";
var previousValue = "";

add_button.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  x++;
  var element = $('<div id="user-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="user_email[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_status[]" value="Unverified" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="auth_key[]" value="<?php echo rand(); ?>" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_member_field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

  element.find('[name="auth_key[]"]').val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000));

  console.log(element.find('[name="auth_key[]"]').val());
  wrapper.append(element);
});

wrapper.on("keyup", "#user_email", function() {
  var isValid = false;
  for (i in availableAttributes) {
    if (availableAttributes[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
      isValid = true;
    }
  }
  if (!isValid) {
    this.value = previousValue
  } else {
    previousValue = this.value;
  }

});

wrapper.on("click", "#remove_member_field", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
    $(this).closest('#user-fields').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <center><b>Team Members</b></center>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Member's Registered Email</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Role in Project</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_email[]" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_status[]" value="Verified" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="auth_key[]" value="10" placeholder="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-member-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="member-fields"></div>
    <p class="help-block"><i>To add member please register new User, if already not registered.</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
value="<?php echo rand(); ?>"
```

is generating a random number on server side once requesting the site.
You have to use

```
Math.random()
```

from javascript.